# trying to plot mouse hovering interactive graph with bokeh in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, hover, bokeh

I am new to bokeh and trying to plot a graph.I have three lists say,

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
y=[1,2,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5]
c=[50,40,30,20,10,60,50,40,30,20,10]

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="Range", plot_height=350, plot_width=800)
p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha=0.5
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Value'

p.line(x,y)
show(p)
```

I want to have a sort of time series like step function graph, where the x-axis is a continuous series of time (the list x) and the y-axis is the event (the list y)  i.e. y-axis should have markings only till 5 (like 1,2,3,4,5) and the plotted points when hovered over by mouse pointer should show the corresponding value stored in c.

so for example for when time is x=1, then y=1, and c=50.

so that I know by looking at the x-axis at what time where the person was (out of 5 places 1,2,3,4,5 on the y-axis) and by placing my mouse what was the value at that time (the list c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to show tooltips only at specific points I wold add circles and set them as the only hover renderers like this:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HoverTool

x=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]
y=[1,2,1,1,1,1,3,4,5,5,5]
c=[50,40,30,20,10,60,50,40,30,20,10]
source = ColumnDataSource({'x': x, 'y': y, 'c': c})

p = figure(x_axis_type="datetime", title="Range", plot_height=350, plot_width=800, tooltips = [('time', '@x'), ('place', '@y'), ('value','@c')])
p.xgrid.grid_line_color=None
p.ygrid.grid_line_alpha=0.5
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Value'

lines = p.line('x','y', source=source)
circles = p.circle('x','y', source=source)

p.select_one(HoverTool).renderers = [circles]

show(p)
```